# How to do port translation when using an address translation map with cassandra?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, compose-db, scylla, cassandra-python-driver

I'm trying to connect to a scylladb cluster on compose using the Address Translation Map.

I can only get the code working if I hard code the port when instantiating the Cluster instance:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.policies import AddressTranslator
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider

################################################################################
# our variables

address_map = {
    "10.0.24.69:9042": "sl-eu-lon-2-portal.3.dblayer.com:15227",
    "10.0.24.71:9042": "sl-eu-lon-2-portal.2.dblayer.com:15229",
    "10.0.24.70:9042": "sl-eu-lon-2-portal.1.dblayer.com:15228"
}

username = 'scylla'
password = 'changeme'

port = 15227

################################################################################
```

Next a class for translating the addresses:

```
class ComposeAddressTranslator(AddressTranslator):

    def set_map(self, address_map):
        # strip ports from both source and destination as the cassandra python
        # client doesn't appear to support ports translation
        self.address_map = {key.split(':')[0]: value.split(':')[0] for (key, value) in address_map.items()}

    def contact_points(self):
        return [value.split(':')[0] for (key, value) in address_map.items()]

    def translate(self, addr):

        # print some debug output
        print('in translate(self, addr) method', type(addr), addr)

        trans_addr = self.address_map[addr]
        return trans_addr
```

Now let's connect:

```
compose_translator = ComposeAddressTranslator()
compose_translator.set_map(address_map)

auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(
                            username=username, 
                            password=password
                            )

# if the port parameter value is removed from below, we are unable 
# to establish a connection

cluster = Cluster(
            contact_points = compose_translator.contact_points(),
            address_translator = compose_translator,
            auth_provider = auth_provider,
            cql_version = '3.2.1',
            protocol_version = 2,
            port = port
            )

session = cluster.connect()
session.execute("USE my_keyspace;")
session.shutdown()
```

It appears that the cassandra python library does not support port translation with the [translate method](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/policies.html#cassandra.policies.AddressTranslator.translate)?  You can see below in my debug output that the addr passed into the translate method is a string ip address value without the port:

```
in translate(self, addr) method <class 'str'> 10.0.24.69
in translate(self, addr) method <class 'str'> 10.0.24.71
```

My Environment:

```
$ pip freeze | grep cassandra
cassandra-driver==3.10

$ pip freeze | grep cassandra
cassandra-driver==3.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other Cassandra drivers such as the node driver support port translation.  The nodejs [translator documentation](http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/address-resolution/#the-address-translator-interface):

```
MyAddressTranslator.prototype.translate = function (address, port, callback) {
   // Your custom translation logic.
};
```

Above you can see that the translator receives both the ip address and the port.

However, I don't believe the current Cassandra python driver supports port address [translation](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/policies.html#cassandra.policies.AddressTranslator.translate):

```
translate(addr)
```

> Accepts the node ip address, and returns a translated address to be used connecting to this node.

Here you can see that the translator only receives the ip address.